# Codeless enable/disable tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I am looking to know if there is a way to enable/disable tests without committing a change in test files.

For example, in xunit, the [Fact] attribute controls the execution; wondering if this attribute can be altered without modifying the code in test file to add 'Skip'. Like, if there is a easier way, say a UI, or a tool, which can be used to quickly switch the tests?

Comment: Do you use VisualStudio IDE? Do you need that configuration for CI or just locally?

Comment: sorry for replying late, yes I use vs 2017 and this is for CI.

Comment: Please provide more information: what tools do you use? What build tool do you use? If maven it possible to skip test by maven